# C++ member variable pointers

Tags: c++

I am sure this is a basic question, but I keep receiving memory access errors when I think I am doing this correctly.

What I want to do:

```
class A{
  string name;
  string date;
}

main{
  A *a = new A();
  a->name= someFunct();
  a->date= someFunct();

  B b;
}
class B{
  A *a;
  printf("%s", a->name); //retrieving data set in main
}
```

I essentially need to assign some overall settings in one class and want to be able to access those settings throughout the application in the most efficient way.

Comment: Where is B used and how does it initialize A?

Comment: I don't follow the last part - I don't think that will compile-as-is and I'm not totally sure what you meant. Is that definitely the same `A *a` in B?

Comment: @Rup So what I want to do is create an object in main, and assign data to the member variables.  Any other object created from main I want to be able to access that data.  So clearly I am doing something wrong, and I don't know what?

Comment: `main` needs a return type. You may not omit it. It must be `int`. It needs a parameter list like every other function. Class definitions must end in a `;`. Class definitions shall not contain procedural code. `printf` doesn't take `std::string`s. Tidy up the typos, present the testcase you're _actually_ using, and then we'll talk!

Comment: this is just so far from valid C++; `class B` can't directly contain a `printf`, main needs to be a function like `int main()`, etc. and since it's not enclosed in a function we don't know where the `printf` is called. you have no mention of creating an instance of `class B` much less setting `a` or calling a function that might be the one containing `printf`. unless you can either paste the code you have that does compile, or give a reasonably valid program, no one is going to be able to help much more than probably the post that mentions calling `printf("%s", a->name.c_str());`

Comment: @shelleybutterfly - I would presume this should be read as a sort of pseudo code

Comment: @jamesj: I agree, but that is not acceptable! The OP has a concrete problem with a concrete piece of code, and he has decided instead to give us something else that has no meaning.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I agree, it's a bad question because of that. But it still has an answer

Comment: not meaning to be unkind, just that it's so outside the norm of even pseudo-code thats I don't understand what really is going on. any one of many things: lack of initializations, incorrect param to printf, or even the calls to someFunct() could be causing a "memory access" error, but I don't really see any way to tell without something more substantially correct; perhaps the @JohnnyCplusplus can update the question with a closer representation of what his program is actually doing.

Comment: @jamesj it's certainly not as if we are unwilling to help, but we can't really help without enough information. if the OP can provide us a better snippet of code, he can always either update it here, or open a new post when he's ready. it's just that there are lots of other questions needing answers, and this currently, IMO, does not actually rise to the level of anything that can be understood as a complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Andreas' answer, you are not initialising *a in B. Just because they are named the same does not mean that they are pointing to the same thing. You need to say something like

```
b.a = new A();
```

in your main. Otherwise b.a is an empty pointer.

Ie. You need to create an instance of a on your b instance. Alternatively to keep a bit closer to your current code you could do:

```
int main(char* args[]){
  A *a = new A();
  a->name= someFunct();
  a->date= someFunct();

  B b;
  B.a = a;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal - I was just sticking to the pseudo code style used in the original example. If this was real code then yes it would, as well as a proper signature etc.

Comment: If this is pseudo-code, then who's to say that the original code was wrong? Or that `B.a = a` is valid? :)

Answer (score 3):

You're passing a std::string to printf, you need to pass a c string.

```
printf("%s", a->name.c_str())
```

Comment: Ah, yes this is a sneaky problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will be useful too:

```
class A
{
public: //you forgot this
        //defaut is private
   string name;
   string date;
};

int main()
{
   A *a = new A();
   a->name = someFunct();
   a->date = someFunct();

   delete a; //maybe you should do it
}

class B
{
   A *a;

   .....
   printf("%s", a->name.c_str());
   .....
};
```

Comment: @jamesj In original source author doesn't use class B at all

Comment: exactly, so how can the *a in B be pointing to anything. I agree about your comments about defaulting to private though, missed that.

Comment: @Tomalak - true. A typo on my part.

Comment: @jamesj: I suggest also fixing in your answer :)